# how to output the FQDN of a CNAME?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have a server

```
$Server = "server1"
```

how do i write output the FQDN of this server?

I tried the following

```
write-host "$([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($Server).HostName)"
```

but it doesnt output anything

i tried this

```
(resolve-dnsname $server).name
```

it just outputs back server1, not the actual name

Comment: from what i can tell, that will ONLY return the `.HostName` of the target. i don't think the hostname and the FQDN are the same thing.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey so there isnt a way to get the actual server name? because the actual server name is like UXW23jk.domain.com...thats what i want to output

Comment: you SHOULD be getting something back from that call IF the `$Server` is a valid system name. that specific call has apparently been deprecated in favor of `::GetHostEntry()`, but those both _should_ return the same info. ///// apparently on domain-joined systems you should be seeing the FQDN in the `.HostName` property of the returned object. ///// i would likely look into using `Get-ADComputer` to see what it returns.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue. What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I have actually 2 servers i am looping through. $Server[-1]. maybe thats why its not working? i wrapped this around $($Server[-1]) but i still cant get it ot work with Christopher Peters solution even

Comment: @TheMadTechnician version 5

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I have actually 2 servers i am looping through. $Server[-1]. maybe thats why its not working? i wrapped this around $($Server[-1]) but i still cant get it ot work with Christopher Peters solution even

Comment: Does `$server[-1]` return what you expect it to? You shouldn't have to wrap that, it should work as `[system.net.dns]::GetHostByName($server[-1]).HostName`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician yes, as a mtter of fact [system.net.dns]::GetHostByName($server[-1]).HostName is returning server1. but not the FQDN

Comment: Is server1 in DNS and does your system have a DNS server address configured? `(resolve-dnsname $server).name` will provide the FQDN if it has an A record for the DNS server your client is using. You can use the `-Server` parameter to specify a different DNS server.

Comment: @AdminOfThings yes, so server1 is alias/CNAME we created to point to the FQDN UCiu56.domain.com (example)

Comment: @AdminOfThings i have just opened a powershell session and i tried this write-output ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName(('server1'))).Hostname it just outputs server1

Comment: @AdminOfThings i tried this too (resolve-dnsname $server).name it just returns server1 back

Comment: Do your dns suffixes on your system include the dns zone you are querying against?

Comment: @AdminOfThings not sure i understand...

Comment: From your system, run `nslookup server1`. Does the `Server: ` name/address that you are expecting respond to your request? If so, does that server contain the dns zone that has your CNAME record or at least have a conditional forwarder to that zone?

Comment: @AdminOfThings actually was trying that as you posted lol. it does not return what i thought it would, but it does return some other weird server name and ip address

Comment: @AdminOfThings ok so i just tried the nslookup on the name i am wanting outputted, and i got this field: Non-authoritative answer with the server name and address.

Comment: Does `ping server1` also give you the FQDN answer you are looking for? It should give you the cname target if all is configured properly. Regarding the DNS suffixes, if you run `ipconfig /all`, you will see the DNS Suffix Search List at the top of the output. When you try to do a lookup by hostname only, it will append each of those suffixes to your hostname and try to find each of those FQDNs (hostname + suffix) in your configured DNS server. If it gets a hit, it returns that result. I'm not saying they are a problem, it is just a factor to consider.

Comment: @AdminOfThings ok so i dont care for the FQDN anymore. i am fine with IP address, since that also allows me to access the folder (the reason i wanted to output the FQDN is to allow quick copy paste to network to the drive.) so since IP address also can network to a drive, \\IPADDRESS\s$, i was able to get the IP address like this: Resolve-DNSName $server | select-object IPAddress however i am getting back this @{IPAddress=10.89.1.0} why am i not just getting back 10.89.1.0

Comment: When you pipe to select-object, you are outputting an object with properties that you select. Just access the property directly if you only want the value like `(Resolve-DNSName $server).IPAddress`.

Comment: @AdminOfThings i also found out that i could use -expand : Select-Object -Expand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work >>

```
$server = "test server"

write-output ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName(($server))).Hostname
```

used this website for assistance
https://www.powershellbros.com/powershell-tip-of-the-week-get-fqdn/

one document against write-host ..
https://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/

Comment: hmm...didnt work :/ can you show it in the context of a write-host?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include write-host >> typically write-output is probably better use
https://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/



$server = "itdv-sccm"

$fqdn = ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName(($server))).Hostname

Write-Output $fqdn

Comment: what if i have 2 servers lets say and i have to loop like this $server[-1]. how would i integrate that? i tried  ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName(($($server[-1])))).Hostname but didnt do anything

Comment: You could do a simple array....or could look into grabbing data from a csv as well

$servers = "itdv-sccm", "itdv-prtsrvp03"


foreach($server in $servers)
{
Write-output ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName(($server))).Hostname

}

Comment: oh i already have the loop going. and i have to call the server this way $server[-1]

Comment: i have just opened a powershell session and i tried this write-output ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName(('server1'))).Hostname it just outputs server1

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-6

the [-1] is going to call the last item of the array. I guess knowing you creating an array and how you are going to iteratively move through it is going to be key to how you are going to design it

Comment: if you put 'server1' you are not passing a variable ...in powershell variables have the dollar sign

Comment: yes but i decided to just explicitly include the server in quotations and it just outputs back server1, not the FQDN.

Comment: Gotcha..are you able to ping this server just by the host name?

Comment: With what we tested and what you have on the other thread looks like some kind or weird DNS resolution issue

Answer (score 1):

You could use WMI for this:

```
$computer = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName "Server1"
'{0}.{1}' -f $computer.DNSHostName, $computer.Domain
```

or the same using CIM:

```
$computer = Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName "Server1"
'{0}.{1}' -f $computer.DNSHostName, $computer.Domain
```

Comment: Get-CimInstance : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication:
Cannot find the computer. Verify that the computer exists on the network and that the name
provided is spelled correctly.and for wmi, Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)